# Brackets, Less не компилирует Css

Tags: css, less, adobe-brackets

Периодически в Brackets
При сохранении изменений в файле стилей .less не производиться, генерация этих изменений в .css
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Сдайте анализы.

Answer (score 0):

Так же было, решил проблему

Правка - Добавлять префиксы при сохранении, а не при изменении 
Перезапуск

Пока вроде работает корректно

Comment: @Elena, вроде бы ответ - перезапустить при возникновении таких проблем.

Comment: @Qwertiy, больше на комментарий похоже, а не на ответ